# how to check if value is a last csv entry?

Tags: javascript, csv

i have long csv with data... like 1,2,3,........,120
i want to check if it is last one. but how to do it with javascript?

here iam splitting all csv and getting each one separate.

```
var movieSRC = CSV;
if (movieSRC.indexOf(',') > -1) {
    movieSRC = movieSRC.split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < movieSRC.length; i++) {
         ***//need to check if it is a last one!!!***
         movies.push(movieSRC[i]);
    }
```

Comment: `if (i === movieSRC.length - 1) { ... }`?

Comment: is it really so simple??

Comment: It depends what you need to do with it...

Comment: here's VisioN's solution -> http://jsfiddle.net/tJ5aL/ it works

Comment: what about the lines? there is no comma separator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Using split() method
var arr = movieSRC.split(',');    //give you an array
var element = arr[arr.length-1];  //get the last element of array

//Ussing substring() and lastIndexOf()
var element = movieSRC.substring(movieSRC.lastIndexOf(',')+1);
```

As suggested in the comment, you could also use Array.pop() method, however it will remove the element from the array:

```
var element = movieSRC.split(',').pop();
```

Comment: @VisioN, doesn't it remove the element from the array?

Comment: @VisioN, please [check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) its compatibility (including Opera, Safari) is unknown yet.

Comment: Array `pop` unknown? That must be a joke. Most probably MDN doesn't know the exact versions of Opera and Safari that started to support this good old method.

Comment: @VisioN, I am not sure, I just had a look, that is what on the site. Anyways I can add your suggestion to the answer...